# azure wep app gallery installation of ghost http 500 error

Tags: azure, ghost

I have a new Ghost app install from the app gallery on azure, the install finished and I have gone to the URL for the web app and I get this error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented  the webpage from displaying.

I have tried going to the ?admin? section with the /ghost/ and still get HTTP 500

I have seen another post which suggests /ghost/setup/ and still get HTTP 500

I have seen another post which suggests /ghost/signup/ and still get HTTP 500

I've tried deleting the Web App and recreating but still get the same errors. There doesn't seem to be any documentation anywhere on azure either

Found this error

[31m
 ERROR:[39m [31mCannot find module 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'[39m

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
     at require (module.js:385:17)
     at Object. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
     at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
     at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
     at require (module.js:385:17)

The Node Installation seems to be wrong...

D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\

the Azure Installation has installed 2 node folders:

node-v11-win32-ia32

node-v11-win32-x64

Comment: This seems to be a common issue with ghost on Azure. Dig into Kudu might be your best option at this point... https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service). E.g. https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net/
2. Navigate to `site\wwwroot`
3. Run `npm install --production`

More info [here](https://www.rocky.wtf/ghost-is-unable-to-start-due-to-missing-dependencies/)...